# Autosys File Watcher - looking for create date

Tags: autosys

I am wanting to setup a File Watcher job to monitor a file shared in an Active Directory environment.  The filename is always the same, and does not contain the date/time.  And the file stays in it's location until replaced, as others might use the file.

How can I create a File Watcher job to look for a file less than 24 hours old?

AutoSys Automation AE - Release:11.4.6.20180302-b425

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way of doing that. I would suggest, if you know when the file is created have the FT start little after the creation or deleting the file after it is processed.